# Building a LSTM for Stock Prediction

Tags: r, keras, lstm

I am building my first LSTM model using keras in R. I believe my problem is with my input_shape and I would appreciate your help.

I am using closing stock returns at time t to predict returns at t+1 
so i believe my input shape should equal 1.

Here is my code:

```
#LSTM Model 
model <- keras::keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 50, return_sequences = TRUE, dropout = 0.2, weights = 0.01, input_shape = 1
             )%>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 100, return_sequences = FALSE, dropout = 0.2, weights = 0.01
            )%>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear')

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  loss = "mse"
)
```

However when I run this I get the following error message:

```
error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_12: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and suggestions on what I should do?

Thank you for your time.

I believe the information I provided should be enough to answer my question. If not, here is my full code to get the data and results

```
#Downloading Stock Price and normalize to returns    
BRI_Price <-quantmod::getSymbols("BBRI.JK", src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("2015-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-02-17"), by = "day", auto.assign = FALSE) 
Returns_Closing <-quantmod::dailyReturn(BRI_Price$BBRI.JK.Close) 

#Training and Testing Data 
train_size <- round(.9*nrow(Returns_Closing)) 
test_size <- nrow(Returns_Closing) - train_size 
train <- Returns_Closing[0:train_size,] 
test <- Returns_Closing[train_size:nrow(Returns_Closing),] 

#Reshape into X=t and Y=t+1 
x_train <- Returns_Closing[1:train_size,] 
y_train <- Returns_Closing[2:train_size+1] 
x_test <- Returns_Closing[train_size:nrow(Returns_Closing),] 
y_test <- Returns_Closing[468:nrow(Returns_Closing),] 

#LSTM Model 
model <- keras::keras_model_sequential() %>% 
layer_lstm(units = 50, return_sequences = TRUE, dropout = 0.2, weights = 0.01, input_shape = 1 )%>% 
layer_lstm(units = 100, return_sequences = FALSE, dropout = 0.2, weights = 0.01 )%>% 
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear') 

model %>% 
compile( optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(), loss = "mse" ) 
#train the model 
Train_Model <- model %>% fit( x = x_train, batch_size = 100, epochs = 1, validation_data = list(x_test, y_test) )
```

Comment: What the shape of your training dataset. Check this [article](https://stackabuse.com/time-series-analysis-with-lstm-using-pythons-keras-library/).